# Determine element value before updating it

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like my xslt to check the value of a field before updating it. So when an approval email is sent to the system with the keywords :Approved" or "Denied", the xslt runs an updates the approval in the system accordingly. If the approval has already been approved or denied, then xslt should not update it again. Below is the extract of my xslt which updates the field:

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

<xsl:template match="/" name="Approval_Update">

```
    <!-- *********************** -->
    <!-- BEGIN: Define Variables -->
    <!-- *********************** -->
    
    <!-- find the profile link recid of the email sender -->
    <xsl:variable name="profilelink_recid">
    <!-- for each RelatedBusinessObject -->
      <xsl:for-each select="BusinessObjectList/BusinessObject/RelatedBusinessObjectList/RelatedBusinessObject/BusinessObject">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@Name = 'Employee'">
            <xsl:for-each select="./FieldList/Field">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@Name = 'RecId'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- find the profile link category of the email sender -->
    <xsl:variable name="profilelink_cat">
      <!-- for each RelatedBusinessObject -->
      <xsl:for-each select="BusinessObjectList/BusinessObject/RelatedBusinessObjectList/RelatedBusinessObject/BusinessObject">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@Name = 'Employee'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Employee'"/>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <!-- find subject and subjectID -->
    <xsl:variable name="emailSubject" select = "BusinessObjectList/BusinessObject/EmailMessage/Subject" />
    <xsl:variable name="emailSubjectID" select = "BusinessObjectList/BusinessObject/EmailMessage/SubjectID" />
    <xsl:variable name="emailBody" select = "BusinessObjectList/BusinessObject/EmailMessage/Body" />
    <xsl:variable name="EmailStatus" select="substring-before($emailBody,' ')"/>



        <xsl:for-each select="BusinessObjectList/BusinessObject">   
            <xsl:element name="BusinessObject">
                            <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="'FRS_ApprovalVoteTracking'"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <!-- Set Transaction as 'Update'.  It will try to update existing record using UniqueKey value, otherwise it will fail. -->
        <xsl:element name="Transaction">Update</xsl:element>
        <!--Unique Key List-->
        <xsl:element name="UniqueKeyList">
            <xsl:element name="UniqueKey">
                <xsl:element name="Field">
                    <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="'TrackingID'"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
                <FieldList>
                    <!-- Fields -->
                                <xsl:for-each select="EmailMessage/node()">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="name() = 'SubjectID'">
                                            <xsl:element name="Field">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:text>TrackingID</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="Type">System.Int32</xsl:attribute>
                                             <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
                                            </xsl:element>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="name() = 'Body'">
                                            
                                            <xsl:element name="Field">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:text>Status</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="contains($EmailStatus,'Approved')">
                                                <xsl:text>Approved</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="contains($EmailStatus,'Approve')">
                                                <xsl:text>Approved</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="contains($EmailStatus,'Denied')">
                                                <xsl:text>Denied</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="contains($EmailStatus,'Deny')">
                                                <xsl:text>Denied</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="contains($EmailStatus,'approved')">
                                                <xsl:text>Approved</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="contains($EmailStatus,'approve')">
                                                <xsl:text>Approved</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="contains($EmailStatus,'denied')">
                                                <xsl:text>Denied</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="contains($EmailStatus,'deny')">
                                                <xsl:text>Denied</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                            </xsl:element> 
    
                                            <xsl:element name="Field">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:text>Reason</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                            
                                            <xsl:when test="contains($EmailStatus,'Denied')">
                                                <xsl:text>Denied by Email</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="contains($EmailStatus,'Deny')">
                                                <xsl:text>Denied by Email</xsl:text>
                                            </xsl:when>

                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                                            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="$EmailStatus"/> -->
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                            </xsl:element>
                                            

                                        </xsl:when>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </FieldList>
                            <!-- Copy the RelatedBusinessObjectList element-->
                            <xsl:element name="RelatedBusinessObjectList">
                                <xsl:for-each select="RelatedBusinessObjectList">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each> 
        <!--</xsl:element> -->
    <!--</xsl:element> -->
        </BusinessObjectList>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So xslt should check the current status of the approval i.e. if it is "Pending" then it should update if not it shouldn't.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including input, your attempt and expected output **as code** within your question, not pictures in external links.

Comment: Downvoted because the code is supplied only as an image.

Answer (score 1):

The common approach is to have a template that matches the element you want to modify, using a [*predicate*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates). For example:

**XML**

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>Alpha</Name>
        <Color>Red</Color>
        <Status>Good</Status>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Name>Bravo</Name>
        <Color>Green</Color>
        <Status>Pending</Status>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Name>Charlie</Name>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
        <Status>Bad</Status>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <Name>Delta</Name>
        <Color>White</Color>
        <Status>Pending</Status>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Status[.='Pending']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>Denied</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items>
  <Item>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Alpha</Name>
    <Color>Red</Color>
    <Status>Good</Status>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Bravo</Name>
    <Color>Green</Color>
    <Status>Denied</Status>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>Charlie</Name>
    <Color>Blue</Color>
    <Status>Bad</Status>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Name>Delta</Name>
    <Color>White</Color>
    <Status>Denied</Status>
  </Item>
</Items>
```